# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object any idea

Tags: php, date, datetime, post

I'm trying to convert the received date through `$_POST` but I got

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Here is my code:

```
$time = $_POST['order_date'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time, new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
$get_data = $date->format( 'Y-m-d H'); //here is the problem
```

What is the problem with my code?

Can anybody help please?

Comment: So perhaps $date is null, meaning 2nd line returns null, meaning $_POST['order_date'] isnt a valid date.

Comment: Code works fine for me!

Comment: @Rizier123 I've uploaded the code into a online server and its giving me that error. In localhost its working well.

Comment: @Helper What output do you get if you print `$_POST['order_date']` before you use it?

Comment: @Rizier123 eg: 2014-12-02 14:06:26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My answer does not directly answer your question, but you can alternatively try this.**

You can simply implement this using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$time = $_POST['order_date'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H', strtotime($time));
```

However, `$_POST['order_date']` should have [the valid format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) to [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked like a charm. Now I got the idea. Regards

Comment: This answer seems to be working around the problem rather than solving it.

Comment: @vascowhite is working around the problem not solving it alternatively, isn't it? SO answers need to meet such kind of strict rules? Well, either `strtotime` or `DateTime::createFromFormat`, the correct format must be given. That's why I stated `$_POST['order_date'] should have the valid format to strtotime`.

Comment: @vascowhite, I think it is just enough to leave comment here. No need downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$_POST['order_date']` input doesn't seem to be formatted correctly. As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) says, `DateTime::createFromFormat` returns `false` if the `$time` parameter doesn't match the given `$format` string, so a boolean type (non-object).

You should verify your `$_POST` input and catch those errors via checking

```
if(!($date instanceof DateTime))
{
    // you, sir, entered an invalid date!
}
```

to prevent those errors.

Comment: As DateTime::createFromFormat() returns false on error you can simply do `if(!$date){}`.